# ifndef variable triggers when variable is defined

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Why, when I run `make run-e2e-docker` is ifndef activated?  The variable should be set, and yet make determines it not to be.  It's available to the echo commands that run.  If I remove the ifndef, and run the make it prints the variables.

```
run-e2e:
ifndef environment
$(error "You can't run run-e2e directly, choose one of the run-e2e-* tasks ${environment}")
endif
    @echo extra_profiles=${extra_profiles}
    @echo environment=${environment}

run-e2e-docker: override extra_profiles = docker-e2e,dev-performance
run-e2e-docker: override environment = docker
run-e2e-docker: run-e2e
```

Comment: How do you set `environment`?  You don't show anything in the makefile that sets it, and the command line doesn't set it.  So, … where is it set in your opinion?  Did you use `export environment=climate` or something like that?

Comment: It could be set from the top of the file, or it could be set from the command line, but currently it's set from run-e2e-docker using the override option.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `override` (it's not a part of classic `make`).  To the extent I understand conditionals, I'd expect them to be operated on as the makefile is parsed, rather than when the actions are executed.  I've more normally seen such conditionals outside the context of a recipe.  I suspect that if you moved the conditional before the `run-e2e` target, you'd get the same message.  But I might be barking up the wrong tree, or just plain barking mad.

Comment: Put that as an answer and I'll accept it.  I found this in the docs after you mentioned that, so put that in the answer as well... "so they cannot be used to control recipes at the time of execution." https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html

Comment: It's not clear from the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html) that you can put `override` after a rule — the examples don't show that.  That's not to say that you can't, but from my (archaic) point of view, you have oddball dependencies.  OTOH, the conditionals can appear in rules — [Example](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html#Conditional-Example).

Comment: You can put `override` in a target-specific variable.  But, `override` is irrelevant here.  All it does is change the priority of a variable so that instead of a command-line argument being the highest priority setting, the override assignment is the highest priority.  It doesn't make any difference for use with ifdef.  Similarly, target-specific variable values cannot be tested with ifdef because they are not assigned until the recipe is going to be invoked, like automatic variables.  Renaud's answer tells the tale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use make conditionals in your context. They are not evaluated when you apparently think. But you can use the shell conditionals, instead:

```
run-e2e:
    @if [ -z "$(environment)" ]; then \
        echo "You can't run run-e2e directly, choose one of the run-e2e-* tasks"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
    @echo extra_profiles=${extra_profiles}
    @echo environment=${environment}
```

The GNU Make manual says...

> Conditionals control what make actually “sees” in the makefile, so
> they cannot be used to control recipes at the time of execution.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html

Comment: Another option, if you prefer to really stop make altogether, is to use make's `$(if ...)` condition inside the recipe; `$(if $(environment),,$(error ...))`

Comment: Good response.  It won't let me edit the post as my change was less than 6 characters.  All I wanted to add is an '@' before the 'if' so that it doesn't print the conditional code as output.  Maybe the author is able?

Comment: Adding to what MadScientist said. This works well...
$(ifndef $(environment),,$(error "You can't run run-e2e directly, choose one of the run-e2e-* tasks"))